# ThreeJS raycaster off with camera and object having a coordinate greater than 1000000

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, raycasting

I have set up a raycaster in order to perform object selection from my canvas.

It works well for small values of camera.position.x and object.position.x, but my problem is that it doesn't work well when camera.postion.x is a large number, in my case 10 000 000!

It's off by quite a bit, actually, i get a reaction when the mouse pointer is to the right of my object by an entire object length! My guess is that calculating with such huge numbers creates this distortion, but can't be sure.

```
                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

                camera.position.x = 11000000;
                object.position.x = 11000000;

                function onMouseMove( event ) {

                    vector.x = ( (event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft) / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                    vector.y = - ( (event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop) / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

                    raycaster.setFromCamera(vector, camera);

                    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

                    if(intersects.length>0){
                        alert("INTERSECTION " + intersects[0].object.userData.name);
                        }

                }canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
```

I omitted adding of object to the scene and some other stuff so that the post would't be too long. This works when camera.position.x and object.position.x are set to some value less than 1 000 000, for example, although some distortion is present even then.

**EDIT 1**

```
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

                var height = canvas.clientHeight;
                var width = canvas.clientWidth;

                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width/height, 1, 1000);

                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(width, height);
                canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Also, here is a part of my html where 'canvas' div is located, I also tried canvas.offsetLef instead of renderer.domElement.offsetLeft etc..

**EDIT 2**

```
<div id="content" ng-controller="ShippingCtrl">

        <div id="left_panel">

        </div>

        <div id="canvas" style="width:900px; height:600px; border:1px solid white">

        </div>

        <div id="right_pannel">

        </div></div>
```

Comment: I would want to be sure that the domElement and canvas origin coordinates in HTML/CSS are the same and that no margins, browser zoom, or offsets are moving the ray from your intention. Then also that your renderer setSize is also correct. I have never seen a ray miss because of float imprecision.

Comment: I would say you have something wrong in your setup. Maybe a fiddle with your full code would help others to point out the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. But the raycaster finds intersect objects if i rotate and pan my scene with orbitControls.
You found any solution?

Comment: Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/senften/pen/rmBQRa) that hacks the threejs interactive cubes [demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Suspecting floating point rounding errors I walked through the unprojection in Matlab to see what how a different implementation would handle it. I started with the camera matrices in the [codepen](http://codepen.io/senften/pen/rmBQRa) example

Camera Projection

```
 4.951969385147095e-01                         0                         0                         0
                     0     1.428148031234741e+00                         0                         0
                     0                         0    -1.001000523567200e+00    -1.000000000000000e+00
                     0                         0    -2.001000404357910e+00                         0
```

Camera World

```
       1           0           0           0
       0           1           0           0
       0           0           1           0
 4000000     2000000     1000800           1
```

The inverse of the camera projection matrix as calculated by javascript through threejs

inverse camera projection matrix

```
    2.0193986892700195                          0                           0                       0  
                     0          0.700207531452179                           0                       0  
                     0                          0                           0      -0.499750018119812  
                     0                          0                          -1      0.5002500414848328
```

The inverse of the camera projection matrix as calculated by Matlab

```
 2.019398591193624e+00                         0                         0                         0
                     0     7.002075262012054e-01                         0                         0
                     0                         0                         0    -4.997500239490878e-01
                     0                         0    -1.000000000000000e+00     5.002500356257574e-01
```

Multiplying the matrices together (inverse camera projection matrix * camera world matrix)

in threejs

```
    2.0193986892700195                          0                           0                       0  
                     0          0.700207531452179                           0                       0
          -1999000.125               -999500.0625                -500149.8125      -0.499750018119812
           2001000.125               1000500.0625                   500649.25      0.5002500414848328
```

The same calculation in Matlab

camProjectionInv*camWorld

```
 2.019398591193624e+00                         0                         0                         0
                     0     7.002075262012054e-01                         0                         0
-1.999000095796351e+06    -9.995000478981755e+05    -5.001498239682470e+05    -4.997500239490878e-01
 2.001000142503030e+06     1.000500071251515e+06     5.006492356542581e+05     5.002500356257574e-01
```

Using a point at the center of the screen for simplicity [0,0,0.5,1.0] and multiplying through and dividing by w

from threejs

```
     3599999.783405974,        1799999.891702987,        900796.0640709081
```

from Matlab

```
 4.000000000000000e+06     2.000000000000000e+06     1.000796005991391e+06     1.000000000000000e+00
```

there is an accumulation of rounding errors. What I don't quite understand is how C++ (Matlab) and JavaScript (threejs) differ in their handling of IEEE Standard 754 64-bit floating point numbers.

For my use, it is important to retain the world coordinate system of the data so to overcome the picking/floating point problems, I simply translate my scene back to the origin by placing a translation at the top group node using it's position attribute and set the camera to look at that location. I keep my camera and view information separate from my scene so that I can implement multiple views on the same data. Therefore, on my scene object, I implemented

```
center(): THREE.Vector3 {
    let datacenter = this.dataCenter();
    let center = datacenter.add(this.sceneLocation);
    return center;
}

worldBBox(): THREE.Box3 {
    return new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.pathsGroup);
}

protected updateScenePosition(): void {
    this.sceneLocation = this.dataCenter().negate();
    this.scene.position.set(this.sceneLocation.x, this.sceneLocation.y, this.sceneLocation.z);
    this.scene.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate=true;
    this.scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);
}

protected dataCenter(): THREE.Vector3 {
    let dataBBox = this.dataBoundingBox();
    let center = dataBBox.max.clone();
    center.sub(dataBBox.min);
    center.divideScalar(2.0);
    center.add(dataBBox.min);
    return center;
}

protected dataBoundingBox(): THREE.Box3 {
    let bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.pathsGroup);
    this.pathsGroup.worldToLocal(bbox.min);
    this.pathsGroup.worldToLocal(bbox.max);

    return bbox;
}
```

When an object is added to the scene, I call updateScenePosition although it probably isn't strictly necessary since new objects are likely in the roughly the same locale and the visible error is probably already compensated for with the initial objects.

The camera update is then

centerView() : void {

```
    this.look = this.bigscene.center().clone();

    this.camera.position.set(this.look.x, this.look.y, this.look.z+3600); 

    this.camera.lookAt(this.look);
    this.controls.target.set(this.look.x, this.look.y, this.look.z);

    this.light.position.copy(this.camera.position); //headlight
}
```